# .htaccess rewrite or subdomain

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

This is my url is shown at the moment;

```
http://blog.example.co.uk/post?id=152&title=titleofpost
```

This is my htaccess as shown below;

#### To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

#### To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

#### Blog subdomain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blog.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

How can I show the url as;

```
http://blog.example.co.uk/post/titleofpost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+post(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)&title=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /post/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+author(?:\.php)?\?name=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /author/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=302]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^post/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^author/([\w-]+)/?$ author.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Blog subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I require to get `id` and `title` where do I add the `[QSA]`?

Comment: For some reason the links on the post page when clicked add it to the url.
eg a link to another page Review from the post page will appear as 

`http://blog.example.co.uk/post/id/titleofpost/Review`

Is this normal? If I change the link to `/review.php` then it works but this is not ideal. I have many links going to other pages so why is it adding the page name to the friendly url?

Comment: That is due to your use of relative links. You can try to add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks you're a lifesaver. Is there a way I can hide the `id`? and show only `http://blog.example.co.uk/post/titleofpost`